# i want to add route to the main menu in laravel in app.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

This is the link I want to add:

```
 <li><a href="{{ route('categories') }}">categories</a></li>
```

This is the web.php "route file":

```
Route::get('/categories','categories_controller@index')->middleware('auth');
```

I get this error:

> (3/3) ErrorException Route [categories] not defined. (View: C:\new
>   xamp\htdocs\pharmacy_backend\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
>   (View: C:\new
>   xamp\htdocs\pharmacy_backend\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the route a name to use it as route.

```
Route::get('/categories','categories_controller@index')->middleware('auth')->name('categories);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use named route into your application then make sure to use name function after your route definition like this

```
Route::get/post('your-url','YourController@yourFunctionFoo')->name('named.route');
```

and then you can use it anywhere in your application as

```
<a href="{{ route('named.route') }}">Click Me</a>
```